# Border disappears in Chrome when percentage height specified

Tags: css, google-chrome, border, percentage

I have a *div* with 1-pixel-border and *height:29%*. Chrome for some reason renders it without the bottom border.

See http://jsfiddle.net/9WVuC/4/

This issue depends on the actual percentage value and container size; when I change them, border sometimes appears and sometimes disappears. Seems that there is some rounding error in Chrome rendering engine when it's calculating actual *div*'s height. Also, it occurs only if *overflow* and *position* are specified for that *div*.

Is it a known bug and maybe some workaround exists? Of course I can get rid of that percentage values by recalculating height manually and setting it with JS, but it's not very elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

this is because of the `overflow:hidden;` style you have on the div, the border actually appears outside of the div in question, so according to the height of the div (with it being a %) it doesn't take this border into account.

Looking at your code i would recommend moving your `overflow:hidden;` to the containing element of the divs (the `td`) that fixes the problem and will have the same effect on the content of the `class="lower"` element if it overflows.

Comment: This answer I found helpful ... in my case adding some margin to the child element worked ... in case that helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this "bug" by setting height to `height: 28.95%;`

Make sure you do not use tables for layout. They should only be used for tabular data.

Comment: Changing the height percentage only solves the issue for that concrete situation, but if I change the container's height, the border disappears again - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WVuC/12/). Unfortunately, in my situatuion different heights are possible (container can be resized). But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

decrease the height or remove overflow: hidden

```
lower{
height: 28%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border: solid 1px black;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9WVuC/8/)

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the height percentage helps only for concrete container height (see my comment to JimmyRare's answer). `overflow: hidden` is necessary in my situation.

Comment: yeah you are right. The error is caused by border(border-height) of the box. so you must change the height value. better you set height value as 28%.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a rendering issue depending on screen/window size and the element's computed size (with decimals). A workaround for me was to put an invisible `box-shadow` where the border is missing and it fixes the rendering. For the bottom border it would look like this:

```css
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

Comment: didn't fix the issue on chrome for me